# Flash builder doesn't create swf file in custom output folder

Tags: eclipse, compilation, flash-builder

I am trying to build my flex project to a custom output folder.
I am running Flash Builder on windows and I have set the output folder to a custom location.

When I build the project, the SWF file in not generated in the output folder. Instead, I get the folders of my package (e.g. my.package.name generates folder structure my/package/name) and the SWF file in generated in the inner directory.

I know this shouldn't be happening (FB should be generating a SWF file directly under the custom output folder) but can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in your source code. I think you are using **`my.package.name`** in ActionScript class or in `<fx:Script>` tag. Therefore compiled output is creating directory according to package name.

Comment: Plus - the application should always be in the default package.